# C# - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet[]

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to create an array of `Worksheet` of an Excel file but I can not find the correct cast.

This is the code:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(pathFile);
int numSheet = book.Worksheets.Count;
Excel.Worksheet[] sheets = new Excel.Worksheet[numSheet];
sheets = (Excel.Worksheet[])book.Worksheets;
```

I tried with that cast, as you see from the code, but it's redundant.
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel.Sheets is an IEnumerable that can contain Charts and Worksheets, so if you use a loop you can get the desired result.

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(pathFile);
int numSheet = book.Worksheets.Count;
List<Excel.Worksheet> sheets = new List<Excel.Worksheet>(); 
foreach(Excel.Worksheet sheet in book.Worksheets)
    sheets.Add(sheet);
```

If you need it in an array after you can always call

```
sheets.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Years late to the party, however for anyone else, using the linq method OfType:

```
var sheets = book.Worksheets.OfType<Excel.Worksheet>().ToList();
```

That way Charts won't cause problems. If the Excel enumerable property were guaranteed to return a single type then use Cast<> instead.